# How do I disable a SwitchPreference, if another SwitchPreference is disabled?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm working on the Settings activity of my game. I have a notifications section where the user can enable notifications and enable vibration.

I want to disable vibration SwitchPreference if the notifications SwitchPreference is disabled. I have tried `android:dependancy` but all that does is blur the SwitchPreference instead of disabling the vibration.

This is what's inside pref_main.xml

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_title_notifications">
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="@string/enable_notifications"
        android:title="@string/title_enable_notifications" />

    <RingtonePreference
        android:defaultValue="content://settings/system/notification_sound"
        android:dependency="enable_notifications"
        android:key="@string/key_ringtone"
        android:ringtoneType="notification"
        android:summary="@string/default_ringtone"
        android:title="@string/title_ringtone" />

    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="@string/key_vibrate"
        android:title="@string/title_vibrate" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

I have a settings activity and an appcompatpreferenceactivity file. These three files control the settings. What should I do in each file to disable vibration when notifications is disabled?

Edit: Here's the code for MainPreferenceFragment for Settings activity

```
public static class MainPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_main);

            // EditText Listeners
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.key_full_name)));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.key_username)));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.key_birthday)));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.key_email)));

            // notification preference change listener
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.key_ringtone)));

            private SwitchPreferenceCompat enableNotifications;
            private SwitchPreferenceCompat keyRingtone;

            @Override
            public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
                setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);
                enableNotifications = findPreference("enable_notifications");
                keyRingtone = findPreference("key_ringtone");

                enableNotifications.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                        keyRingtone.setChecked(((boolean) newValue));
                        return true;
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by capturing the changes on your first `Switch` and change the value of the second:

```
 public static class MainPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

        private SwitchPreference enableNotifications;
        private SwitchPreference keyRingtone;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_main);

            // EditText Listeners
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.key_full_name)));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.key_username)));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.key_birthday)));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.key_email)));

            // notification preference change listener
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.key_ringtone)));

            enableNotifications = findPreference("enable_notifications");
            keyRingtone = findPreference("key_ringtone");

            enableNotifications.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                    keyRingtone.setChecked(((boolean) newValue));
                    return true;
                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: Where would I include this code? Inside the Settings acitivity `public static class MainPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment`?

Comment: I updated the post and it includes the new `public static class MainPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment`. However, I'm getting errors. `cannot find symbol class SwitchPreferenceCompat`, `cannot find symbol variable root_preferences`, `non-static variable enableNotifications cannot be referenced from a static context`, `non-static variable keyRingtone cannot be referenced from a static context`, `non-static variable keyRingtone cannot be referenced from a static context`, `non-static variable enableNotifications cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: I'm getting `error: incompatible types: Preference cannot be converted to SwitchPreference`. It has to do with these two lines: `enableNotifications = findPreference("enable_notifications");` and `keyRingtone = findPreference("key_ringtone");`.